# python - split the string and print in separate variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split a string and print it in two separate variables, what i am doing is:

```
string = [['SMC/BTC', 3624, 6.31e-06, 6.18e-06],['SKY/BTC', 5038, 0.00212768, 0.00207798],['SQL/BTC', 1596, 0.00011456, 0.00010204]]
a = string[0][0].partition("/")[0]
b = string[0][0].partition("/")[2]
print(a,b)
```

it is showing error:

```
a = string[0][0].partition("/")[0]
TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

I have no idea how to handle this error, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: It runs ok on 3.6

Comment: so the output should be `a= 'SMC'` and `b = 'BTC'`?

Comment: yes, runs are ok on 3.6 and output should be the same.

Comment: if it is run OK what is the problem? Check what ever `string[0][0]` this is. may be you using dymanic indexes and run into 3 element (index 2)?

Comment: I have checked the index string[0][0], it shows value 'SMC/BTC' but when i apply partition, it shows me the above mentioned error

Comment: 6 minutes ago you said, it runs without problem on 3.6? No problem on Python 3.5 and 2.7, btw.

Comment: what is `result_list` ? -- the error is from a portion of code not shown in your question.

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the mentionned behaviour (it does not raise any error). Please post a __real__ MCVE => code that does reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also: don't name `string` something which is a list of lists, and use tuple unpacking to avoid doing the split (partition) operation twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **split** method.

```
string = [['SMC/BTC', 3624, 6.31e-06, 6.18e-06],['SKY/BTC', 5038, 0.00212768, 0.00207798],['SQL/BTC', 1596, 0.00011456, 0.00010204]]
for i in string:
    if "/" in i[0]:
        a, b =  i[0].split("/")
        print(a, b)
```

**output:**

```
SMC BTC
SKY BTC
SQL BTC
```

Comment: I have also tried this, this shows: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: Looks like some of the string does not have a slash. Updated code to handle it.